# Accessibilty service to select the text from different app

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I was working on clipboard copy project. Clipboard manager is working below the android 10 but not in higher version. So i decided to use accessibility service where i need to select the text from cross application and detect the text. But event source is always null while selecting and copying the text from the webpage.
I have tired using the view clicked, view context click events. Actually the event is calling fine but the event source for selected text is always null.

Can anyone help me